# whenever, I run my program in flutter, I am getting this error in console any solution for this?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261 contains a valid JDK installation.

What I tried:

Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace.

Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

1. List item

> BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s
> Exception: Gradle task assemble Debug failed with exit code 1

When I run `flutter doctor -v`

```
G:\projectname>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.22.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.1 at C:\src_vscode\flutter
    • Framework revision f30b7f4db9 (12 days ago), 2020-10-08 10:06:30 -0700
    • Engine revision 75bef9f6c8
    • Dart version 2.10.1


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Waqas Hameed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Waqas Hameed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.15.1

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Web Server (web)             • web-server    • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 86.0.4240.75
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 86.0.622.38

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps:

```
    - flutter pub cache repair
    - cd <YOUR APP FOLDER>
    - flutter clean
```

Comment: Did you try this: flutter pub cache repair

Comment: You can import the latest version of 

shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+2

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src_vscode\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: What is flutter doctor -v result? Please log it.

Comment: [!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

Comment: ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: You have to install Android Studio.

Comment: I am already working in android studio...I don't know what can I do?

Comment: Did you install Dart and Flutter plugins?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the flutter doctor -v result? There was only a few part was in the comment.

Comment: Akif i added doctor -v result in the post, please take a look.